# Update the row with non existing rowkey for hbase?

Tags: hbase

In my understanding when I update the row with existing rowkey with methods such as put, then we insert a new version of the row, however if the rowkey does not exist, it still inserts a new row.
My requirement is that if the rowkey does not exists,then do not insert a new row.

How to do it with hbase Java Client api?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly as it will vastly improve your chances of getting good answers in return and not have your question downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `checkAndPut(rowkey,family,qualifier,CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL,null,put)`
But it checks for existence of a column in a rowkey and then does put.

For checking existence of rowkey ,do a get operation first and check if exists or not and then accordingly proceed with put.

Comment: As explained earlier,If a column is not present,it will not do a put.Also it is not based on assumptions.If you want you can look at complete code.[link]http://ideone.com/I1plTL

Comment: I think you are right. So in that case pls put the complete code example in your answer.

Comment: checkAndPut is just what I needed, thank you so much!